# How do I debug issues using SendKeys in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to set duplex printing in Excel, and the other code posted just doesn't work for me. I tried to debug it, got nowhere, and decided to try and use SendKeys to set the duplex printing option. Code is as follows:

```
Sub SendKeysDuplex()
Dim I As Long
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show

Application.SendKeys "^p", True
Sleep 5000

For I = 1 To 3
    Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
    Sleep 500
Next I
    Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
    Sleep 500
For I = 1 To 4
    Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
    Sleep 500
Next I

        'First sets the option to no
    Application.SendKeys "n", True
        'To make sure we get the right yes
    Application.SendKeys "y", True
    'And confirm the setting
    Application.SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
    'Sheet1.PrintOut

End Sub
```

It opens the print menu just fine - but then the tabs and enters don't seem to do anything. However, if I try to debug the code by stepping through it, it sends the keys to the VBA editor - not to Excel.

How can I debug issues in SendKeys? Is there something else I need to know about opening up menus with Sendkeys?

I managed to get debugging to "work" by creating a bunch of macros with individual SendKeys, assigning those macros to keys, and then pressing the keys in order. It looks like Tab doesn't want to function in the print dialog - it does nothing when it's sent with a sendkey, but it works when manually pressing it. (???)

Comment: maybe you can utilize the findwindow api as well. that may work more smoothly once you have the print dialog box open?

Comment: That looks interesting, I'll take a look into that!

Answer (score 1):

1. only run the sub when the **Excel** worksheet window is active not the **VBE** window. *(in fact, close the **VBE** before running the sub)*
2. replace all `Sleep` command with `DoEvents` commands

Comment: Thanks for the help! It seems like Tab doesn't want to function when the print window is open o_O?